# why are arabic numbers (١٢٣) not accepted in textboxes as real numbers?

Tags: php, magento, numbers, arabic

while developing one of my sites, i noticed that if I enter arabic numbers (١٢٣), they are not interpreted as real number values. Then, I tested a few other sites only to find that they also don't accept arabic numbers.

The problem is, my client seems to require this functionality (accepting arabic numbers).. and I have no idea where to start. My platform is magento (php).

Comment: I have tried to find you an answer, but unfortunately I can't find anything. All "solutions" are to change the arabic numbers into a normal number before you insert it into the textfield... If there are plugins for Magento, you could try a plugin. That's the best advice I can give.

Comment: thanks i appreciate your efforts anyways :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow PHP to accept the Arabic numbers or Persian numbers (Farsi) (١٢٣٤٥),
I developed this easy function:

```
<?php

/*
/////////////////////
This function has been created by Abdulfattah alhazmi
Roles:
To convert Arabic/Farsi Numbers (٠‎ - ١‎ - ٢‎ - ٣‎ - ٤‎ - ٥‎ - ٦‎ - ٧‎ - ٨‎ - ٩‎) 
TO the corrosponding English numbers (0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9)
http://hazmi.co.cc
/////////////////////
*/

function convertArabicNumbers($arabic) {
    $trans = array(
        "&#1632;" => "0",
        "&#1633;" => "1",
        "&#1634;" => "2",
        "&#1635;" => "3",
        "&#1636;" => "4",
        "&#1637;" => "5",
        "&#1638;" => "6",
        "&#1639;" => "7",
        "&#1640;" => "8",
        "&#1641;" => "9",
    );
    return strtr($arabic, $trans);
}
?>
```

**Note:** TO GET THE CORRECT RESULT from text field in your form, you have to use the [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars-decode) function. For example:

```
$mytext = htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['mytext']));
$mytext = convertArabicNumbers($mytext);
```

To keep your code safe, add [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip-tags). For example:

```
$mytext = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['mytext']));
$mytext = convertArabicNumbers($mytext);
```

Please don't hesitate to ask me if you have any further question about this function.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK you need to install an arabic language pack with `./mage install` - see http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Ahmed+J.+Hadi/extension/353/magento-community-modules--arabic-saudi-arabia-language-pack

Comment: I already have installed an arabic language pack.. but that didn't do the trick :(

Comment: @maha can't try it out right now... but then the only option is to path magento (for example the client-side JS validation needs to "translate the numbers")

Answer (score 1):

Strangely Abdulfattah Alhazmi function didn't worked with me, after lot of try & error, the below worked with me.

```
function convertArabicNumbers($arabic) {
    $trans = array(
        "٠" => "0",
        "١" => "1",
        "٢" => "2",
        "٣" => "3",
        "٤" => "4",
        "٥" => "5",
        "٦" => "6",
        "٧" => "7",
        "٨" => "8",
        "٩" => "9",
    );
    return strtr($arabic, $trans);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Arabic numbers are not all the same as Persian. for example, ۴ and ۵ (4 and 5 in Persian) are different from ٤ and ٥ (4 and 5 in Arabic). I think ۶ (6) is also different. so one needs to use Unicode for actual "Persian" numbers (listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_alphabet#Deviations_from_the_Arabic_script)) if they wanted to get correct Persian numbers.