# Arabic numerals in html input textbox

Tags: html, css, arabic

Hi I'm working on a site which is in arabic language. I need to know how to write arabic numerals in a input textbox.

I can write arabic characters. But when I type Arabic Numerals it always end up to This format: 1, 2 ,3... etc. instead of this (٠‎ - ١‎ - ٢‎ - ٣‎ - ٤‎ - ٥‎ - ٦‎ - ٧‎ - ٨‎ - ٩‎)

How can I write arabic numerals in a texbox.

I'm using the following headers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Is there a universal way on doing this that will work on all browsers?

Comment: You have a regular `<input type="text">` which automatically converts any numbers to 1, 2, 3 numerals instead of the entered arabic numerals?

Comment: Yes <input type="text">. I have an arabic keyboard. BUt when I type arabic numbers in my keyboard it always end up to 1,2,3 numerals. Typing arabic characters works just fine but why typing arabic numerals don't work.

Comment: I think this would be helpfull to you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132997/why-are-arabic-numbers-not-accepted-in-textboxes-as-real-numbers

Answer (score 0):

Arabic number has different Unicode value, until you have Arabic keyboard you can't achieve or convert Unicode value on keypress, so it will display in Arabic digits.
you can get the Arabic Unicode values from below link
http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1536&utf8=string-literal

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the **type** in the operating system. if you are using windows, go to regional settings, number format, there you can set which type of numbering you want to use.

On the Other hand, those numbers you are talking about are Indian Numbers, Arabic numbers are these (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and we mistakenly refer to them as english numbers.