# How to change numbers type from arabic to english for a font?

Tags: css, fonts, numbers

I'm supposed to add some modifications to a **PHP** web site which uses a font with Arabic style numbers.
I'm asked to convert the numbers style (language) to the English style (language) using the same font, is that achievable ?

Arabic(red) & English (green) numbering:

[image]

Comment: The title strikes me as strange since you want to convert to [arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals).

Comment: look here, can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132997/why-are-arabic-numbers-%D9%A1%D9%A2%D9%A3-not-accepted-in-textboxes-as-real-numbers

Answer (score 2):

In principle, it is possible to create a font that has alternate glyphs for Arabic digits, selectable with OpenType font features and looking like common (European) digits. However, I do not know any such font, and such an approach would be odd on several accounts. The Arabic digits have been encoded as separate *characters*, and treating the difference between them and common digits as merely a glyph difference would deviate from normal reasonable practices.

Thus, the change, if desired, should be made at the *character* level. The details depend on the context, but the principle is simple: common digits are U+0030...U+0039 and Arabic digits are U+0660...U+0669, both in numeric order, so at the character code level it is simply a matter of adding or subtracting a constant.

Comment: @HazemTaha, using a font editor. That’s off-topic at SO. (And it requires permission from the copyright holder of the font.)